SquareSpace Section Auto-Expand to Footer
I am struggling with a SquareSpace page that doesn't have enough content to fill the vertical height, when the browser window width is resized to between 1025px - 1672px wide.
I would like the highlighted section in the reference image to auto-expand its black background color if the viewport is resized to 1025px - 1672px, to prevent the white gap between the section and the footer.
I only need this fix for desktop, as for tablet and mobile this is not an issue with the current media-queries.
Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!
Site: https://fish-mayflower-586h.squarespace.com/collection
PW: testing78

